# 104, 'Connection reset by peer' socket error, or When does closing a socket result in a RST rather than FIN?

Tags: python, sockets, wsgi, httplib2, werkzeug

We're developing a Python web service and a client web site in parallel.  When we make an HTTP request from the client to the service, one call consistently raises a socket.error in socket.py, in read:

```
(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

When I listen in with wireshark, the "good" and "bad" responses look very similar:

- Because of the size of the OAuth header, the request is split into two packets.  The service responds to both with ACK
- The service sends the response, one packet per header (HTTP/1.0 200 OK, then the Date header, etc.).  The client responds to each with ACK.
- (Good request) the server sends a FIN, ACK.  The client responds with a FIN, ACK.  The server responds ACK.
- (Bad request) the server sends a RST, ACK, the client doesn't send a TCP response, the socket.error is raised on the client side.

Both the web service and the client are running on a Gentoo Linux x86-64 box running glibc-2.6.1.  We're using Python 2.5.2 inside the same virtual_env.

The client is a Django 1.0.2 app that is calling httplib2 0.4.0 to make requests.  We're signing requests with the OAuth signing algorithm, with the OAuth token always set to an empty string.

The service is running Werkzeug 0.3.1, which is using Python's wsgiref.simple_server.  I ran the WSGI app through wsgiref.validator with no issues.

It seems like this should be easy to debug, but when I trace through a good request on the service side, it looks just like the bad request, in the socket._socketobject.close() function, turning delegate methods into dummy methods.  When the send or sendto (can't remember which) method is switched off, the FIN or RST is sent, and the client starts processing.

"Connection reset by peer" seems to place blame on the service, but I don't trust httplib2 either.  Can the client be at fault?

** Further debugging - Looks like server on Linux **

I have a MacBook, so I tried running the service on one and the client website on the other.  The Linux client calls the OS X server without the bug (FIN ACK).  The OS X client calls the Linux service with the bug (RST ACK, and a (54, 'Connection reset by peer')).  So, it looks like it's the service running on Linux.  Is it x86_64? A bad glibc? wsgiref? Still looking...

** Further testing - wsgiref looks flaky **

We've gone to production with Apache and mod_wsgi, and the connection resets have gone away.  See my answer below, but my advice is to log the connection reset and retry.  This will let your server run OK in development mode, and solidly in production.

Comment: The question is indeed why the server send the RST reques. The client has to reset the connection and to inform the 'Connection reset by peer' message. So I think you are on the right track

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've had this problem.  See [The Python "Connection Reset By Peer" Problem](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/iblog/architecture/C551260341/E20081031204203/index.html).

You have (most likely) run afoul of small timing issues based on the Python Global Interpreter Lock.

You can (sometimes) correct this with a `time.sleep(0.01)` placed strategically.

"Where?" you ask.  Beats me.  The idea is to provide some better thread concurrency in and around the client requests.  Try putting it just *before* you make the request so that the GIL is reset and the Python interpreter can clear out any pending threads.

Comment: In the link it seems that the issue is with running the server and the client in the same process. Hence they are subject to the gil.

Comment: Yes, but... You're seeing what looks like the same connection reset even in separate client-server hosts.  I still think that you should mess with sleeps here and there to see if the thread scheduling change helps.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use wsgiref for production.  Use Apache and mod_wsgi, or something else.

We continue to see these connection resets, sometimes frequently, with wsgiref (the backend used by the werkzeug test server, and possibly others like the Django test server).  Our solution was to log the error, retry the call in a loop, and give up after ten failures.  httplib2 tries twice, but we needed a few more.  They seem to come in bunches as well - adding a 1 second sleep might clear the issue.

We've never seen a connection reset when running through Apache and mod_wsgi.  I don't know what they do differently, (maybe they just mask them), but they don't appear.

When we asked the local dev community for help, someone confirmed that they see a lot of connection resets with wsgiref that go away on the production server.  There's a bug there, but it is going to be hard to find it.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you'd get an RST if you do a close which doesn't linger (i.e. in which data can be discarded by the stack if it hasn't been sent and ACK'd) and a normal FIN if you allow the close to linger (i.e. the close waits for the data in transit to be ACK'd).

Perhaps all you need to do is set your socket to linger so that you remove the race condition between a non lingering close done on the socket and the ACKs arriving?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue however with doing an upload of a very large file using a python-requests client posting to a nginx+uwsgi backend.

What ended up being the cause was the the backend had a cap on the max file size for uploads lower than what the client was trying to send.

The error never showed up in our uwsgi logs since this limit was actually one imposed by nginx.

Upping the limit in nginx removed the error.

Comment: OMG, after searching everywhere I find out the 'Content-Length' can be root cause of this error