# easy_install ReviewBoard [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, easy-install, ubuntu, review-board

I have a Kubuntu 10.04 VM image and am trying to install ReviewBoard by following [The Linux Installation Wiki](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/installation/linux/). When I get to the step to **easy_install ReviewBoard**, I encounter a problem I cannot find a solution to. Below is the console output:

```
>> sudo easy_install ReviewBoard
Searching for ReviewBoard
Best match: ReviewBoard 1.0.8
Processing ReviewBoard-1.0.8-py2.6.egg
ReviewBoard 1.0.8 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing rb-site script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ReviewBoard-1.0.8-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for ReviewBoard
Searching for pytz
Reading http://downloads.reviewboard.org/mirror/
Download error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://downloads.reviewboard.org/releases/ReviewBoard/1.0/
Download error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pytz/
Download error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pytz/
Download error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pytz' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pytz
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pytz')
```

I am new to python, but it seems like easy_install cannot decide on a version of pytz. I have read

- [104, 'Connection reset by peer' socket error, or When does closing a socket result in a RST rather than FIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383738/104-connection-reset-by-peer-socket-error-or-when-does-closing-a-socket-resul)
- http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/iblog/architecture/C551260341/E20081031204203/index.html

and it seems like the problem described in those articles has more to do with development than my problem, but I could be wrong.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this? If there is any missing information that would help troubleshoot this, please let me know.

@Ben Hoffstein

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
        Link detected: yes
```

**EDIT:**
I'm not sure if this will be more useful information, but I tried installing the gitplugin for Trac and I received the same issue. So, it's looking like it may be a problem with easy_install.

```
>> sudo easy_install http://trac-hacks.org/svn/gitplugin/0.11
Downloading http://trac-hacks.org/svn/gitplugin/0.11
error: Download error for http://trac-hacks.org/svn/gitplugin/0.11: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly a temporary problem with PyPI host, try again: `easy_install pytz`

Comment: can you do a ping on pypi.python.org ?

Answer (score 0):

like @Tarantula said, it is a temporary pypi service problem, i hit the same yesterday. i tried to ping `pypi.python.org` (or `dig` or `host`) a few times and find there are 2 servers returned by dns server.  and it is because one of the pypi server keep throwing this error for one of the python package request.

so i hard coded the mapping `pypi.python.org` to the good one in `/etc/hosts` basically force pypi.python.org to resolve to the server i wanted and it relieved my pain. of course it is a temporary workaround when we have no control of the external service.

```
# add a line to /etc/hosts
151.101.200.223 pypi.python.org
```

get rid of the line when the service get back to normal.