# Flask IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I am running flask default wsgi server using

```
from resources import app
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

and getting error.can you please take a look..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 596, in process_request_thread
        self.handle_error(request, client_address)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
        self.finish_request(request, client_address)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
        self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
        self.handle()
      File "/home/ranvijay/work/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.11.11-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 216, in handle
        rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
        self.handle_one_request()
      File "/home/ranvijay/work/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.11.11-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 251, in handle_one_request
        return self.run_wsgi()
      File "/home/ranvijay/work/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.11.11-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
        execute(self.server.app)
      File "/home/ranvijay/work/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.11.11-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 184, in execute
        write(data)
      File "/home/ranvijay/work/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.11.11-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in write
        self.wfile.write(data)
    IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Can you provide any more information? Does this happen always? Intermittently? Who is calling your server at the time?

Comment: Since you're using `threaded=True`, I wonder if [this might be of some help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383738/104-connection-reset-by-peer-socket-error-or-when-does-closing-a-socket-resu)?

Comment: we are generating gas pipeline simulations with some calculation if we are hitting more than one concurrent request its happen then again we need to restart server and we are not using gunicorn and nginx server. we are using default server.

Comment: this usually simply means that the browser closed the connection ... because you hit stop or closed the browser or hit reload before all data was transmitted