# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Tags: python

I'm having this nasty error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/script.py", line 44, in <module>
    response_service_k = service_k_lib.service_kData(data, access_token, apifolder)
  File "/home/ubuntu/script_lib.py", line 238, in service_kData
    datarALL.extend(data.result())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/script_lib.py", line 129, in getdata3
    responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 495, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383738/104-connection-reset-by-peer-socket-error-or-when-does-closing-a-socket-resu) the solution for my issue is to place :
`time.sleep(0.01)` strategically in my code. I get the idea of it but I'm not sure I know where the correct spot for it in my code:

This is the relevant code part from  `script.py`  :

```
result= []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_pages) as executor:
    futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata3, page, hed, data, apifolder,additional)) for page in pages]
    for data in as_completed(futh):
        result.extend(data.result())
print ("Finished generateing data.")
return result
```

This is the relevant code part from `getdata3` function :

```
        def getdata3(...)
            datarALL = []
            responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
            if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # 200 for successful call
                responsedata = responsedata.text
                jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
                if "results" in jsondata:
                    if jsondata["results"]:
                        datarALL.extend(jsondata["results"])
            print ("{1} page {0} finished".format(page,str(datetime.now())))
            return datarALL
```

Some info:

My code generates pages.

Create thread per page executing getdata3 (which makes GET request to API)

each thread return the result of a single page.

"merging" results.

**My question:**

Where to put the `time.sleep(0.01)` in order to avoid this error?

Answer (score 21):

you might already figured this out. Any way, I had a similar problem while making post requests in a for loop, which run 400 times, each loop run with two requests and a last request after exiting the loop. I found out while making API requests the server (check_mk) was not ready, still compiling some hots and service data. So I placed the `time.sleep()` just before the each request and that fixed the problem. I don't know how often you make the requests but I'd try it this way:

```
def getdata3(...)
    datarALL = []
    time.sleep(0.01)
    responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
    if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # 200 for successful call
        responsedata = responsedata.text
        jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
        if "results" in jsondata:
            if jsondata["results"]:
                datarALL.extend(jsondata["results"])
    print ("{1} page {0} finished".format(page,str(datetime.now())))
    return datarALL
```

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70379603/python-script-is-failing-with-connection-aborted-connectionreseterror104) by the same user posting the problem, it might be due to your internet connection. I had the same problem and changed my internet connection to another network and the issue was solved for me. Then you can give it a try changing your internet network.