# Connection aborted: RemoteDisconnected ('Remote end closed connection without response') after approx 5 mins of inactivity when sending POST

Tags: python, sockets, flask, waitress

I have the idle timeout set to 60 minutes. However, tests with a Python client talking to a Python server, the connection resets by peer approx 5 mins of inactivity when sending POST. The activity is still happening on the server side even after connection is reset or disconnected.

```
import requests
import logging
import flask
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=f'%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s')

@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    app.logger.info("before_first_request")

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    app.logger.info("before_request")

@app.route('/run', methods=['POST'])
def run(redirect_url="",additional_testng_parameters=""):
    url = "http://192.168.1.8:7070/" + "run"
    app.logger.info("url is:" + url)
   
    session = requests.Session()   
    app.logger.info("Request placed for " + url)
    response = "Text"
    try:
        response = session.post(url=url, timeout=3600)
        resultdata = response.headers['Content-Type']
        app.logger.info("Response received for : " + url + " is:" + str(response.status_code))
        app.logger.info("Response received for : " + url + " is:" + str(resultdata))
        response = make_response("Execution is successful")
    except Exception as err:
        app.logger.error(err)
    return response

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def server_error(err):
    app.logger.exception(err)
    return "There is some error on Test Invoker side", 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Roughly after 5 minutes getting below error message

```
ERROR app waitress-0 : ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Below are few references but it does not resolve my problem

[requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051989/requests-exceptions-connectionerror-connection-aborted-connectionreseterro)

https://www.pythonfixing.com/2022/01/fixed-aborted-remotedisconnected-end.html

Comment: Is the connection passing through a proxy/router? If so, that likely has its own idle timeout handling that is killing the connection before your timeout elapses. Have you tried enabling TCP keep-alives on the connection?

Comment: No, the connection is not passing through proxy/router. Yes I tried tried enabling TCP keep-alive but it didn't worked.

Comment: Below piece of code helped me to resolve the problem:                                      
import socket
from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection

HTTPConnection.default_socket_options = (
    HTTPConnection.default_socket_options + [
        (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 45),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 10),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 6)
    ]
)

Comment: Rather than editing "RESOLVED" into the question, please post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Or consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that's [identical to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72527833/6243352). I've removed the edit per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289345/6243352).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import socket
from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection

HTTPConnection.default_socket_options = (
    HTTPConnection.default_socket_options + [
        (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 45),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 10),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 6)
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error while using Gunicorn server for fastapi. I solved it by setting '--timeout' to a value greater than 30.

Answer (score 0):

I found Voidy's solution to work but modified it like so:

```py
class KeepAliveTransport(sentry_sdk.HttpTransport):

    def _get_pool_options(self, ca_certs):
        opts = super()._get_pool_options(ca_certs)
        opts["socket_options"] = urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection.default_socket_options + [
            (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1),
            (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 45),
            (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 10),
            (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 6),
        ]
        return opts

sentry_sdk.init(transport=KeepAliveTransport)
```