# Do AWS Lambdas share some state between runs?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The reason I'm asking that is that I have a lambda that doesn't do much except calling an API using python's `requests` library.
It runs fine every 15 minutes, but after some time(~1 day) it starts to get errors on every run. Every change to the code of lambda resets this cycle.

That made me curious. Do AWS Lambdas share some state between runs?

Comment: What errors exactly? Lamdbas are nos supposed to share nothing beteween states, could it be a cold start issue?

Comment: @yorodm The error I see is exactly like one described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383738/104-connection-reset-by-peer-socket-error-or-when-does-closing-a-socket-resu

Comment: Yes, they can if reused. See container reuse: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

Comment: @dmigo It would be more helpful if you show us your code so we can see what's happening inside and outside your handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jarmod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271415/jarmod) answered in the comments. Lambdas do share some state between runs.
[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) there is an article on the topic.